# Get value of input in jquery by its starting name

Tags: javascript, jquery, jsp

Hi I have a bunch of input box's in my jsp and each having a different name but they share a portion of name same. 
Here is example:

```
<input type"text" name="sequence_1" value="1" />
<input type"text" name="sequence_3" value="5" />
<input type"text" name="sequence_4" value="6" />
<input type"text" name="sequence_7" value="67" />
<input type"text" name="sequence_8" value="3" />
<input type"text" name="sequence_10" value="23"/>
```

And these list can grow any length and ending number can be anything.
For these text boxes I need to access them in javascript and need to change their  values dynamically.
How do I do that? Is there any way to access the input box values only by using the starting name?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the attribute starts with selector:

```
var $inputs = $('[name^="sequence_"]');
```

Better yet, add a `class` to those elements to group them and select by that. This method will be quicker.

Comment: Thanks Rory, I used the class method to get all the elements and it worked fine. $(".text3").filter(function() {
  console.log(this.value);
  this.value = '1';
  console.log(this.value);
 });

Answer (score 0):

```
Better approach is place all input fileds in a class or field-set, like 

 $(".Myclass").each(function () {
var ar=[];
var name= $(this).attr('name');
ar.push(name;
});

$.each(ar, function (index, item) 
{
     alert(item);
});

i htink that is exactly what you are looking for.
```

Answer (score 0):

I used the class method to get all the elements and it worked fine.
And here is the code:

```
$(".text3").filter(function() {
    console.log(this.value);
    this.value = '1';
    console.log(this.value);
});
```

Here I am trying to change the value of input element to 1